Бот не приветствует нового пользователя
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS])
async def new_members_handler(message: Message):
    await message.reply("Добро пожаловать")

Пишу бота на aiogram 2.9, и не могу понять ошибку, в группе бот пишет при добавлении нового участника сообщения, а в другой группе не пишет, права у обоих ботов одинаковые, в чем может быть проблема? (поправка, в группе, где бот не пишет, там 200+ человек)

какие права надо боту дать, чтобы код срабатывал?
